# Java FX, weird behavior from Label

Tags: javafx

I have managed to fix the below issue by using the Text class instead of Label, however I would still like to understand the behavior.

I am trying to create a pane with an image and some text below that image.

I want both the text and the image to be centered inside of the pane.

I also want the text to stick to the bottom of the pane while the image to stick to the top of the pane.

Below is the rough code that achieves what I want. The problem is, If I run the code, the image comes out a little off center. The label also doesn't appear.

If I resize the stage with my mouse, the layout seems to fix itself. The image becomes fully centered and the text appears. Please explain, is this some kind of a bug?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.subtract;

public class TestApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        Label label = new Label("some text");


        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);

        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        pane.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        borderPane.setTop(imageView);
        borderPane.setBottom(label);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(imageView, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER);
        imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(subtract(pane.heightProperty(), label.heightProperty()));

        imageView.setImage(new Image("file:C:\\pathToFile.jpg"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 200, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a StackPane and simply change the alignment of the Nodes . For Label: Pos.TOP_CENTER , for ImageView: Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER. The problem here might be that the `AnchorPane` Height and Width return 0 before you resize the Stage . Try printing the values.

Comment: You could also invoke `borderPane.requestLayout();` after `primaryStage.show();`. As @GOXR3PLUS mentioned AnchorPane height might be 0.